# Question on vector fields

Tags: vector-analysis

Which ones are vector fields? (I checked my answers)

Temperature of room at given point

The gravitation that object with mass creates **(x)**

The density of an object at given point

Function $f: \Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}^3  $ **(x)**

Function $f: \Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}  $

Gradient of function $f: \Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$ **(x)**

Derivate of function $f: \Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}  $

Speed of a water molecule in a river

Function $f: \Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2  $ **(x)**

Function $f: \Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}  $

Tangent of a circle at given point

Did I got them right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, temperature is a scalar, and so is density! Those are both what are known as "scalar fields." Also, speed is a scalar.

The gradient is also a vector field!

Comment: Of course :) I edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I would have said speed is a vector... or does speed means magnitude of the velocity vector in common English usage?

Comment: Also I think the tangent of a circle at a given point is a vectorial quantity, at least if that means the tangent vector at the point. On the other hand the angle made by the segment connecting the origin of the circle with the point (or its sin/cos/tan) is a scalar quantity.

Comment: No problem ELEC! And GFR, speed does conventionally mean magnitude of velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Gradient of a function is also a vector field